# Unable to understand code -newbie

Tags: python

I am new to python ( started 1 week ago) and this is the first time i am doing coding so i am not able to understand fairly simple things as well.

can you explain this function to to me? i understand that a function is being defined with 2  input required self and my_object, but what is happening next? please explain like you would to a newbie.

```
class chain():
    def __init__(self, my_object):
        self.o = my_object

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        x = getattr(self.o, attr)
        if hasattr(x, '__call__'):
            method = x
            return lambda *args: self if method(*args) is None else method(*args)
        else:
            prop = x
            return prop
```

Comment: That's pretty advanced code. I suggest you come back to it in a while after you've learned more of the basics of Python.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is about questions with answers, less about providing you with explanations for code you do not understand. If you have specific problems, cosider studying [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and your exception / expectation that do not get met by your code and I am sure SO will help you out.

Comment: 1) Despite being new, doesn't sound you tried to find out on your own. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ 2) Why do you need this? What are you trying to do other than reading other's (complicated) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `chain` is not a Function, it's a Class.

A class in simple words is a definition of an object. (say Car)

Now the `__init__` function of the class simply defines what's "in it" meaning what variables or properties does it has. Say for example a class `Car`:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,maxspeed,color):
        self.speed = maxspeed #So what's defined under **__init__** is a property of a class.
        self.color = color
```

So here Class car has speed and color as variables(or attributes or properties)

Now there are methods , of simply function that control the behaviour of the object and it's functionalities.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,maxspeed,color):
        self.speed = maxspeed #So what's defined under **__init__** is a property of a class.
        self.color = color
    def accelarate(self):   #Method to increase the speed of car object.
        self.sepped = self.speed + 10
```

Now the method you have is a magical one , `__getattr__`

Say a scenario where you want to acess the brand of the car , now you haven't define `self.brand` in it's `__init__` function so you you'll get an error when you call it like:

```
>>>red_car = Car(100,red) #Creating an object named red_car of class Car
>>>red_car.color
>>>'red'
>>>red_car.brand
>>> Attribute Error , Class car dosen't has attribute brand
```

Now remove this error when calling an undefined property for a object or put simple we tell tell the class what to do if an undefined variable is called we use the method `__getattr__`.

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return attr.upper()

d = Dummy()
d.does_not_exist # 'DOES_NOT_EXIST'
d.what_about_this_one  # 'WHAT_ABOUT_THIS_ONE'
```

In the above code `does_not_exist` property (attribute) is NOT define but still we are not getting error as the getattr catches it and does as instructed. In this case it catches `attr` capitalises it and returns it rather than throwing an error in your face.

Comment: Thanks a lot. really appreciate the efforts. I got all of it.

Comment: @RiyaArora Please don't mark my answer as accepted just because I put a good effort in it, accept the best answer in all, irrespective of the effort put in!

Answer (score 0):

The class `chain` has a constructor that takes an argument `my_object` and assigns it to an instance variable `self.o`.

The method `__getattr__` is a special magic method that has been overridden to delegate calls to the initial `my_object` variable we first received.

The result of the delegated call is checked for a method named `__call__`. If present, it is called and the returned value is returned. If not, the value itself is returned as-is.

Comment: There's no need for that. You don't know anything about the reasons why this code was written.

Comment: I was searching for examples of method chaining and i found this code to be reduced. So it wasn't written to work but as a problem code to apply method chaining.